# Show that $\mathbb{R}^d$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k}\times\mathbb{R}^{d-k}$ for $d>k>0$ integers.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

I would like to show this, here is my starting point

Consider the mapping $f : \mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^{k}\times\mathbb{R}^{d-k}$
defined as $f(v)=((v_1,...,v_k),(v_{k+1},...,v_d))$

Then we have $f(\alpha v+\beta w)=((\alpha v_1+\beta w_1,..., \alpha v_k +\beta w_k), (\alpha v_{k+1}\beta w_{k+1},..., \alpha v_d +\beta w_d)) = (\alpha(v_1,...,v_k) + \beta(w_1,..., w_k), \alpha(v_{k+1},...,v_d) +\beta(w_{k+1},..., w_d))=\alpha f(v) +\beta f(w)$

where the two last equalities follows from the fact that $\mathbb{R}^{k}\times\mathbb{R}^{d-k}$ is a vector space. First, am I correct until now ?

Now I would like to know what kind of argument can I use to show that this linear mapping is bijective, if it is of course ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Define an inverse. Or calculate the kernel (it should be $\{0\}$), and the result follows because both are finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @user480840 Calculate the kernel can be useful only if one knows that the dimension of $\Bbb R^k\times\Bbb R^{d-k}$ is $d,$ but then it is in fact useless because one can prove more easily directly that two vector spaces having the same dimension are isomorphic.

Comment: Defining an inverse seems like a straightforward thing to do.

Comment: This is the sort of exercise that I hope you only have to do once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already proven, that $f$ is linear. Let us assume that $f(v)=0$, then $(v_1,\dots,v_k)=(v_{k+1},\dots, v_n)=0$. But $v=(v_1,\dots,v_k,v_{k+1},\dots, v_n)$, so it follows that $v=0$. Hence $f$ is injective.
Now we know that the dimensions of both vector spaces are equal to $d$. Therefore $f$ is already a isomorphisms between the two spaces. Of course it is also easy to see that $f$ is surjective, for any $((v_1,\dots,v_k),(w_1,\dots, w_{d-k}))$ we choose to map the element $(v_1,\dots,v_k,w_1,\dots, w_{d-k})$ and get $f((v_1,\dots,v_k,w_1,\dots, w_{d-k})) = ((v_1,\dots,v_k),(w_1,\dots, w_{d-k}))$.

Comment: Thank you a lot it is clear ! I have a question about the notation, here we use the notation $((v_1,...,v_k),(v_{k+1},...,v_d))$ to talk about an element of $\mathbb{R}^{d}\times\mathbb{R}^{d-k}$, this notation is different from the usual notation of elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. $(v_1,...,v_n)$ instead of $((v_1),...,(v_n))$) but $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the n-th product of $\mathbb{R}$ is this means that both notations are equivalent ?

Comment: They are different when you compare them as sets, because their elements are not the same. However, as we just proved, they are isomorphic as vector spaces, which means that we can treat them as if they were the same.